# Depth First Search Empty Set Error

Tags: python, dictionary, collections, set, graph-theory

I'm making a program that determines whether or not a directed graph is strongly connected. The graph consists of 2 strings, 1 pointing to the other, and an optional numerical edge weight (defaults to True if no number).

I have a defaultdict(dict):

```
import collections
myDefaultDict = 
        {'A': {'B': True},
         'B': {'C': True},
         'C': {'D': True, 'E': True},
         'D': {'A': True},
         'E': {'C': True}})
```

I then have a set of the strings:

```
myNewSet = {'D', 'E', 'C', 'A', 'B'}
```

I then call my Depth First Search function:

```
for i in myNewSet:
    newSet = graph_DFT(i)
    print(newSet)
    break
def graph_DFT(start):
    functionSet = set() # Contains all visited nodes
    myStack = []
    myStack.append(start)
    if not myStack:
        node = myStack.pop()
        for neighbor in myDefaultDict[node]:
            if neighbor not in functionSet:
                functionSet.add(neighbor)
                myStack.append(neighbor)

    return functionSet # Return the set with the visited nodes
```

The problem is the `print(newSet)`. This example graph, is strongly connected. That is you can reach every vertex from one vertex. However `print(newSet)` displays:

```
set() # But it should be equal to myNewSet, because this is a strongly connected graph
```

Why is my `newSet` empty? Shouldn't it be equal to `myNewSet`? I need it to, because this depends on how I handle the rest of my program, so I might be doing something wrong in my graph_DFT function.
Thanks for any help!

Comment: `if not myStack` is never `True`, as you appended to the list in the previous line

Comment: I thought that that meant `while myStack not empty`. If not how do I make it so it is that?

Comment: `while myStack: ...`

Comment: @MosesKoledoye I changed it to that but getting the same result.

Comment: You should use a [*bottom-up*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-down_and_bottom-up_design) approach. And note also that the graph is not *strongly connected*, as you can't reach others starting from `E`

Comment: @MosesKoledoye ahh my bad. Do you mind elaborating on what a bottom-up approach is? In my eyes I don't see anything wrong with my DFS code.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye Never mind I entered in your first edition of your comment. Now that I added in the second edition it worked! Thanks so much! If you would like to formally answer this question with that I would be happy to accept it and reward you with rep! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @MosesKoledoye:
I simply change:

```
if not myStack:
```

To

```
while myStack:
```